# How do I re-order columns with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do I use CSS grid and via CSS set the order of columns.

Example of 3x3 grid using CSS grid

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

[image]

But, if I try to change the order of the columns using grid-column the auto-layout fails

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "column-1 column-2 column-3";
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}

.fruit { grid-column: 3 / 4; }
.color { grid-column: 2 / 3; }
.cost { grid-column: 1 / 2; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried using `order`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}

.fruit { order: 3; }
.color { order: 2; }
.cost { order: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

The rows have become columns and the columns have become rows

[image]

I tried a `grid-template-areas` like this

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "column-1 column-2 column-3";
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}

.fruit { grid-area: column-3; }
.color { grid-area: column-2; }
.cost { grid-area: column-1; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

That ended up squashing all the rows into one row

[image]

How do I change the order of the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it `grid-auto-flow: column;`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}

.fruit {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.color {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.cost {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* don't forget this */
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}

/* adjust the grid-column value like you want */
.grid *:nth-child(3n + 1) { /*OR .fruit */
  grid-column:2;
}
.grid *:nth-child(3n + 2) { /*OR .color */
  grid-column:3;
}
.grid *:nth-child(3n + 3) { /*OR .cost */
  grid-column:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify like below. You only specify the position of two columns and the third one will be set automatically

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense; 
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
.grid>* {
  background: orange;
}


.grid *:nth-child(3n + 1) { 
  grid-column:2;
}
.grid *:nth-child(3n + 2) { 
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fruit">Apple</div>
  <div class="color">Red</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.00</div>
  <div class="fruit">Banana</div>
  <div class="color">Yellow</div>
  <div class="cost">$1.20</div>
  <div class="fruit">Lime</div>
  <div class="color">Green</div>
  <div class="cost">$0.75</div>
</div>
```